# My WCF IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest and BeforeSendReply methods are being called twice

Tags: .net, wcf

I have implemented some message inspection using IDispatchMessageInspector in WCF. The AfterReceiveRequest and BeforeSendReply are both being called twice for each web method request. Any ideas why?

Using .NET 4.5.1

Comment: Is it [`IDispatchMessageInspector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the server-side or is it [`IClientMessageInspector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispacher.iclientmessageinspector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the client-side?

Comment: Sorry, it's the IDispatchMessageInspector on the server side. I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide your current implementation?

Comment: OK I have figured it out - it was because I had implemented it for both service and endpoint. Thanks anyway.